# ? generic in C++, mostly defined as template

Tags: c++, c++11

I am stuck into a weird problem of converting Java generics to equivalent C++ templates. Now, I have abstract class in Java defined as below:

```
template <class T, class K>
public abstract class A<K extends FirstClass<someclass>, T extends SecondClass<? extends anotherclass>> {
```

Now, in java I know class is assigned to ? on compile time which extends anotherClass. But, in C++ I could not find a way to achieve this. Any helps?

Comment: C++ templates are not generics. There is nothing in C++ that works like extends clause in Java generic parameters. Try just dropping those: `template <class T, class K> class A /* nothing here */ {`.

Comment: not sure, but this works in C++ too template <class T, class K>
class A:K::FirstClass<someclass>, public T::SecondClass

Comment: my problem is implementing T extends SecondClass<? extends anotherclass> for which I used T::SecondClass<?::anotherclass>. Is there any way around for ? used here

Comment: @TarunGupta you want to assert that `K` derives from `SecondClass<something derived from anotherclass>` ?

Comment: This is not equivalent to what you have asked at all. `K::FirstClass` and `K extends FirstClass` are totally different things.

Comment: "implementing T extends SecondClass ... " there is nothing to implement.

Comment: @n.m. OP means *"implementing `T extends SecondClass<? extends anotherclass>`"* which is a constraint of `T`

Comment: right Piotr! so ? itself a template which extends anotherClass. Not sure If I could able to explain you being a noob in C++

Comment: @TarunGupta somethin like this -> http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/af29619b48fd6c89 ?

Comment: @n.m., there is no keyword `extends` in vanilla C++, but you can probably construct something of a kind using SFINAE, `enable_if` and `is_base_of`, uh?

Comment: @bipll You can SFINAE out bad template arguments, but you don't have to.

Comment: @n.m. but you can verify constraints in a static assert, making it similar to a java compile time error. I'm afraid you misread the question

Comment: @n.m. So you don't think Java's `extends` is the same as `enable_if<is_base_of>`?

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki Yes, but the only thing this buys you is a set of less obscure compiler errors. It does nothing to programs that use the template correctly.

Comment: @bipll Get a correct Java program and a correct C++ program. Remove enable_if and compile the C++ program. Now remove extends and compile the Java program. Since results are likely to be radically different, I'd wager that yes, extends and enable_if do different things.

Comment: @n.m. remove all static asserts from a well-designed C++ program, and try to guess what all error messages mean

Comment: @Piotr I never said one doesn't need static asserts. I said they don't serve the same purpose as Java's extends.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the declaration of class `A`:

```java
public abstract class A<K extends FirstClass<someclass>
                      , T extends SecondClass<? extends anotherclass>>
```

the parts `K extends FirstClass<someclass>` and `T extends SecondClass<? extends anotherclass>` define constraints on generic type parameters `K` and `T`. This allows to use those types in contexts where one would normally put any concrete type that satisfies the constraints, and at the same time it prevents users from instantiating the class with types that don't.

In C++ this works slightly different. As long as the instantiated parts of a class template are valid when a template parameter is substituted by a template argument, compilation succeeds. You could therefore declare a regular class template with two type template parameters and that will probabaly work fine. However, if you *do* need a compile-time error if a template type does not satisfy certain conditions, then you can use a `static_assert` inside the body of your class.

`K extends FirstClass<someclass>` is easy to verify, for that you could use [`std::is_base_of`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_base_of).

`T extends SecondClass<? extends anotherclass>` is a little bit more complicated, since `T` can be derived from any `SecondClass` instantiation, whose template type is, in turn, derived from `anotherclass`. This can be checked by verifying that a pointer to `T` can be implicitly converted to a pointer of type `SecondClass<U>*`. Type `U` can be deduced from a function call. Once you extract `U`, you can again apply the `std::is_base_of` trait. `void*` can serve as a fallback call parameter if the implicit conversion fails.

Both traits can be implemented as follows:

```cpp
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>

template <typename U>
auto T_extends_SecondClass_impl(const SecondClass<U>*) -> std::is_base_of<anotherclass, U>;

auto T_extends_SecondClass_impl(void*) -> std::false_type;

template <typename T>
using T_extends_SecondClass = decltype(T_extends_SecondClass_impl(std::declval<T*>()));

template <typename K>
using K_extends_FirstClass = std::is_base_of<FirstClass<someclass>, K>;

template <typename K, typename T>
class A
{
    static_assert(K_extends_FirstClass<K>::value && T_extends_SecondClass<T>::value, "!");
};
```

[**DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bccd5f28f6ddc38e)

Comment: Thanks Piotr for your help, I am also trying to implement below public interface PositioningMethod<T extends RadioSignal<? extends RadioDevice>>,. Can you help me on this?

Comment: Oops! I could able to solve that as well with the solution provided. Thanks again